# Can I access the browser cookies usingCordova cookie master?

Tags: cordova, cookies, cordova-plugins

Some browser URLs (http://domain:port, for instance) already contain cookies. Can I access these cookies using Cordova? I'm using [this](https://github.com/kristianhristov/cordova-cookie-master) plug-in.

When I try to access a cookie, I get an error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Fixed grammar errors and clarified wording.

Answer (score 0):

yes. you can access cookies using this plugin. If you are using Webviews in your application. I have tried both on android and IOS 8 to 11.3 using this cookie master plugin.